# How to stop UIWebView bouncing vertically in phonegap 3.0

Tags: ios, cordova

Have tried many suggestions from this and other forums, including setting "DisallowOverscroll" to "true". Is this broken in phonegap 3.0 by any chance ?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Make certain changes in `config.xml`,

If you are using it for Android, then use

```
<preference name="disallowOverscroll" value="true" />

<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
```

And for IOS, use like

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />

<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
```

Hope this helps you.

**EDIT**

Do a `cordova build` after you have made changes in the `config.xml` file so that the changes affect to your project. The above steps would solve your problem only after you do a `cordova build`

Comment: Thanks - when I create a fresh project this works - both for 2.9.0 and 3.0.0 - so must be some code I modified ;(... !

Comment: I shall add it as an edit to the answer, but @RoryStandley and anyone else who is having the problem even after following this answer, you need to do a `cordova build` after you do this for the changes to take effect on the project.

Comment: webviewbounce was superseded by DisallowOverscroll. As of Cordova 3.6.3, it does not apply to Windows Phone.

Comment: Works for me in Cordova 5.0.0

Answer (score 8):

In the file AppDelegate.h, after initialized the MainViewController, you could disable this bouncing by set the scrollView class inside the webview by :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    ....................

    self.viewController.webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
    return YES;
}
```

The configuration value in the file config.xml was not used, I searched all in Cordova project.

Answer (score 1):

this is method i've used in xcode way.
i dont know how to solve that issue in phonegap
maybe this few codes give you idea

in viewdidload:

```
webView.scrollView.delegate = self;
[webView.scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];



-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

{

```
if (scrollView.contentOffset.x > 0  ||  scrollView.contentOffset.x < 0 )
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.y, 0);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

For Cordova 3.x and above I believe you can set up your `(void)webViewDidFinishLoad` in `MainViewController.m` as follows :

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)theWebView {
    // Black base color for background matches the native apps
    theWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    theWebView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
    return [super webViewDidFinishLoad:theWebView];
}
```

Tested: Cordova 3.4, 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

In your AppDelegate.m file , the "(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.." section should look like this:

```
/**
 * This is main kick off after the app inits, the views and Settings are setup here. (preferred - iOS4 and up)
 */
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds];
#else
        self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds] autorelease];
#endif
    self.window.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
        self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
#else
        self.viewController = [[[MainViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
#endif

    // Set your app's start page by setting the <content src='foo.html' /> tag in config.xml.
    // If necessary, uncomment the line below to override it.
    // self.viewController.startPage = @"index.html";

    // NOTE: To customize the view's frame size (which defaults to full screen), override
    // [self.viewController viewWillAppear:] in your view controller.

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    self.viewController.webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
    return YES;
}
```

Just add **self.viewController.webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;** before the **return YES;**