# Cordova - IOS webview is moving

Tags: ios, cordova, webview

weird issue.. On Android my webview is static (i.e. I cannot move the app up and down) but on IOS I can move the entire webview up and down (therefore causing the header at the top to move up and down which is a bummer :()

I need the webview to not move up and down so my header doesn't move as the webview does... it works find on Android :(

Comment: Are you referring to bouncing ?? If so you can disable bouncing on your webview in the interface builder.

Comment: Thankyou for using the correct terminology, I have found some solutions now.. Will try when I get home from work.

FYI:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799517/how-to-stop-uiwebview-bouncing-vertically-in-phonegap-3-0
looks like a possible solution..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sombody else asked the question but used correct terminology, the issue is that webviewbounce wasn't disabled for IOS.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799560/1332999

### Ashis Kumar's (correct but not marked answered) answer:

Try using below one in your `config.xml`,

If you are using it for Android, then use

```
<preference name="disallowOverscroll" value="true" />

<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
```

And for IOS, use like

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />

<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hopefully, there's always someone who asks without knowing the correct terminology so I can find it too! :)